# How do I unit test my OpenID Connect callback?

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core, identityserver4

I've got my Identity Server 4 project all up and running on .NET Core 2.0, and I've got an Angular front-end connecting to it, which when I try to access gives me the correct OpenID Connect login window (in my case it's Azure AD), and when I log in everything works wonderfully.

Now the time has come to put some functionality behind the callback, so that on my side I can create entries in my own user table when people log in, and read their claims to grant them permission to things in my system. But I can't for the life of me figure out how to write automated tests to cover the callback. All of my attempts at mocking/faking tokens, or calling the callback URL directly (even re-using working calls captured by Fiddler) throw errors.

I've looked in to hybrid flow, which i think is what I need, but I cannot work out how to get the bearer token from Azure AD, let alone pass that to the callback. I thought about having a fake Relaying Party, but that seems a little overkill for a few simple unit tests.

I've tried Googlging all manor of search terms, and every time I seem to be getting close, something doesn't fit. So I'm here, asking for help.

Thanks.